# How to add CSS to a webpart in SharePoint 2013?

Tags: sharepoint-online, web-part, css, style.css

[image]

I would like to know how can I add CSS to web part to make level with news roundup webpart?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is advisable to add css in a .txt file and then link it in the Content Editor webpart.

This will make it easier to update the css whenever required without trying to edit the page

Steps:

1) Create a .txt file in SharePoint Designer

2) add your css within the style tag

3) On the page, add the content editor webpart

4) Link the txt file in the Content Editor webpart properties

5) Stop Editing and Save the Page.

Answer (score 1):

You can Add CSS using script editor web part by editing page.

1. Edit page.
2. Add Script editor web part and add CSS snippet in it with style tag.
3. Stop Editing and Save the Page

Click [here](http://community.bamboosolutions.com/blogs/sharepoint-2013/archive/2013/05/20/how-to-use-script-editor-web-part-in-sharepoint-2013.aspx) for the more information.